# Generate 2 sum(combinations) from 2 lists and then compare the index of those lists for matches

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I volunteered to help a colleague of mine to combine fatty acids with a certain threshold.  There are only 2 acids that exceed this threshold when you combine all of the oils together, so they are my limiting factors.  I found a sum(combination) method that works how I would like for each acid on its own but now I need to compare those results against each other to make sure that if one threshold is met the other isn't exceeded e.g. if Canola, Coconut and Sesame have a threshold of oleic acid that is less than 131 but the combination of these oils gives me a sum of linoleic acid over 131, I cannot use that combination.  This is the code I have so far:

```
import itertools

Coconut_oleic = 6
Canola_oleic = 62
OliveOil_oleic = 71
PeanutOil_oleic = 48
SesameOil_oleic = 39
SunflowerOil_oleic = 30
ButterFat_oleic = 24

Coconut_linoleic = 2
Canola_linoleic = 22
Olive_linoleic = 10
Peanut_linoleic = 32
SesameOil_linoleic = 41
SunflowerOil_linoleic = 59
ButterFat_linoleic = 3




myList = [Coconut_oleic, Canola_oleic, OliveOil_oleic, PeanutOil_oleic, SunflowerOil_oleic, SesameOil_oleic, ButterFat_oleic]
myList2 = [Coconut_linoleic, Canola_linoleic, Olive_linoleic, Peanut_linoleic, SesameOil_linoleic, SunflowerOil_linoleic, ButterFat_linoleic]

for i in range(len(myList)):
    for combinations in itertools.combinations(myList, i):
        if 0 < sum(combinations) < 131:
            print('Oleic',combinations, sum(combinations))
            
for i in range(len(myList2)):
    for combinations in itertools.combinations(myList2, i):
        if 0 < sum(combinations) < 131:
            print('Linoleic',combinations, sum(combinations)
```

Comment: are you asking for a way to iterate through all non-empty tuples of the elements in `myList` and separately `myList2` and return those tuples-which could be of length 1 or longer-whose sum is less than 131? Or is there a different question that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly similar to what you had, just using some formats that are a little easier to work with. The main step is merging the two results together where their combinations are the same... which since we filtered them out earlier, we're left with just combinations that both have < 131.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

oliec = [['Coconut', 6],
         ['Canola', 62],
         ['OliveOil', 71],
         ['PeanutOil', 48],
         ['SesameOil', 39],
         ['SunflowerOil', 30],
         ['ButterFat', 24]]
oliec = pd.DataFrame(oliec, columns=['oils', 'threshold'])

linoliec = [['Coconut', 2],
            ['Canola', 22],
            ['Olive', 10],
            ['Peanut', 32],
            ['SesameOil', 41],
            ['SunflowerOil', 59],
            ['ButterFat', 3]]
linoliec = pd.DataFrame(linoliec, columns=['oils', 'threshold'])

oliec_results = []
for i in range(len(oliec.oils)):
    for combinations in itertools.combinations(oliec.oils, i):
        combined_thresh = oliec[oliec.oils.isin(combinations)].threshold.sum()
        if combined_thresh < 131:
            oliec_results.append([combinations, combined_thresh])
oliec_results = pd.DataFrame(oliec_results, columns=['combinations', 'threshold'])

linoliec_results = []
for i in range(len(linoliec.oils)):
    for combinations in itertools.combinations(linoliec.oils, i):
        combined_thresh = linoliec[linoliec.oils.isin(combinations)].threshold.sum()
        if combined_thresh < 131:
            linoliec_results.append([combinations, combined_thresh])
linoliec_results = pd.DataFrame(linoliec_results, columns=['combinations', 'threshold'])

joined = linoliec_results.merge(oliec_results, on='combinations', suffixes=['_linoliec', '_oliec'])

print(joined)
```

Output:

```
                                     combinations  threshold_linoliec  threshold_oliec
0                                              ()                   0                0
1                                      (Coconut,)                   2                6
2                                       (Canola,)                  22               62
3                                    (SesameOil,)                  41               39
4                                 (SunflowerOil,)                  59               30
5                                    (ButterFat,)                   3               24
6                               (Coconut, Canola)                  24               68
7                            (Coconut, SesameOil)                  43               45
8                         (Coconut, SunflowerOil)                  61               36
9                            (Coconut, ButterFat)                   5               30
10                            (Canola, SesameOil)                  63              101
11                         (Canola, SunflowerOil)                  81               92
12                            (Canola, ButterFat)                  25               86
13                      (SesameOil, SunflowerOil)                 100               69
14                         (SesameOil, ButterFat)                  44               63
15                      (SunflowerOil, ButterFat)                  62               54
16                   (Coconut, Canola, SesameOil)                  65              107
17                (Coconut, Canola, SunflowerOil)                  83               98
18                   (Coconut, Canola, ButterFat)                  27               92
19             (Coconut, SesameOil, SunflowerOil)                 102               75
20                (Coconut, SesameOil, ButterFat)                  46               69
21             (Coconut, SunflowerOil, ButterFat)                  64               60
22                 (Canola, SesameOil, ButterFat)                  66              125
23              (Canola, SunflowerOil, ButterFat)                  84              116
24           (SesameOil, SunflowerOil, ButterFat)                 103               93
25     (Coconut, Canola, SunflowerOil, ButterFat)                  86              122
26  (Coconut, SesameOil, SunflowerOil, ButterFat)                 105               99
```

Comment: I agree with the idea of Grismar that combining both thresholds under a single oil title would be best, but wanted to keep the code as close to what you had as possible while presenting a new tool.

Comment: Thank you so much for all you help and wisdom. I knew python was the best way to do this but I have little to no experience with it. I tried excel but it was overly complicated. I plan to take a python camp soon, so thank you once again for all your insight and help!

Answer (score 1):

The programming problem that you describe can be solved with a few improvements to your code:

- instead of defining all the values as single variables and then combining them in 2 lists, try keeping all the values in a single dictionary, so they are easier to use together and you don't end up defining every product twice; it's all a single definition
- this also means you don't have to loop over them twice, or alternatively use one index to access them both, with the risk of there being differences between the two defined lists
- you're only interested in outcomes that have *both* totals below 131, so you need to represent that (with a logical `and` for example)

For example:

```
import itertools


# oleic and linoleic content of oils
oils = {
    'Coconut oil': (6, 2),
    'Canola oil': (62, 22),
    'Olive oil': (71, 10),
    'Peanut oil': (48, 32),
    'Sesame oil': (39, 41),
    'Sunflower oil': (30, 59),
    'Butter fat': (24, 3)
}

for i in range(len(oils)):
    for c in itertools.combinations(oils.keys(), i):
        if (0 < (o := sum(oils[part][0] for part in c)) < 131 and
                0 < (l := sum(oils[part][1] for part in c)) < 131):
            print(f'The combination {c} has oleic content {o} and linoleic content {l}')
```

Note the use of the walrus operator `:=` to remember the computed value in a variable. It's needed twice, once to see if the value is acceptable and then again to be printed, and computing it twice would be wasteful.

Output (partial):

```
... 
The combination ('Sesame oil', 'Butter fat') has oleic content 63 and linoleic content 44
The combination ('Sunflower oil', 'Butter fat') has oleic content 54 and linoleic content 62
The combination ('Coconut oil', 'Canola oil', 'Peanut oil') has oleic content 116 and linoleic content 56
The combination ('Coconut oil', 'Canola oil', 'Sesame oil') has oleic content 107 and linoleic content 65
...
```

However, it seems that the problem is a bit silly? Adding two oils together and adding up their indivual oileic or linoleic acid content doesn't really make sense? It would seem that the acid content of the combination would just be directly proportional to the amount of each oil you add to the mixture.

Which means every combination is fine, since all the individual values are below 131. If instead you were looking for mixtures with a combined value below, say, 40 - that would be a more sensible problem (and trickier, because there could be many different mix ratios of the same three oils that would work).

Comment: Thank you so much for all you help and wisdom. I knew python was the best way to do this but I have little to no experience with it. I tried excel but it was overly complicated. I plan to take a python camp soon, so thank you once again for all your insight and help!

Comment: You're welcome - if you feel this answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark next to it, so your question no longer appears as 'unanswered'